# how can i generate a box-shadow rather than a drop-shadow? Qt/c++ 6.4.1

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, cross-platform, desktop-application

i'm trying to create a box-shadow effect for my customs widget, but i can't find a way to do that!.

Using `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` class generate a shadow that is the copy of the shape of the widget itself and put that copy behind the widget. So, when i set a opacity of 50% to my widget, the shadow is seeing trought the widget, and what i want to achive is something more like the box-shadow effect pressent in the web CSS styles, for example:

#### css generated:

https://i.ibb.co/mG1XXG2/box-shadow-qt-ask1.png

#### QGraphicsDropShadowEffect generated:

https://i.ibb.co/y680RKx/box-shadow-qt-ask2.png

As you can see, both of my elements has a shadow, and a opacity of 50%, the css generate haven't a shadow visible trought the semi transparent div element, but the shadow generated by `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` can be seeing thounght the semi transparent widget, there's some way to achive to create a custom shadow that behave like css box-shadow but on my Qt/c++ widget?

Sorry if i'm not clear enoungh, i'm not an expert speaking english.
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Have you looked at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-dropshadow.html ?

Comment: yes, but there's nothing related with what i want, also i read the source code on github and i can't figure how to implement a custom shadow that do what i want, so i decided to ask here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheat would be to group your object + drop shadow as a single item. Whilst making that entire object invisible, you copy the entire item with a dummy OpacityMask. Then, you apply the opacity to the OpacityMask.

For example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#ccc" }
    Frame {
        id: butterflyWithBoxShadow
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        visible: false
        padding: 15
        background: Item {
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.leftMargin: butterflyWithBoxShadow.padding * 2
                anchors.topMargin: butterflyWithBoxShadow.padding * 2
                color: "grey"
                opacity: 0.5
            }
        }
        Frame {
            id: frame
            padding: 1
            background: Rectangle {
                border.color: "blue"
                border.width: 1
                color: "#ffe"
            }            
            Image {
                id: butterfly
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                source: "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/185841a46dd1440d87e6fbf464af7849/data"
                smooth: true
            }
        }
    }
    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: butterflyWithBoxShadow
        source: butterflyWithBoxShadow
        invert: true
        opacity: slider.value
    }
    Frame {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: parent.height * 8 / 10
        background: Rectangle { }
        Slider {
            id: slider
            from: 0
            to: 1
            value: 0.8
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: oh! thank you, i will try to translate this logic to c++ and i tell you what i did could do

Comment: well with c++ i did something based on what you did in QML, what i did is to create a baseFrame that i use to render the content of the widget that i want to apply the shadow, then i create the customWidget based on that baseFrame, and the logic is that the custom widget has 1 base frame that will have the shadow effect and the opacity effect is applyed to the customWidget itself. result: https://i.ibb.co/qNjppbN/drop-Shadow-Final-Solution.png